# Add a border on a word in indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, typesetting, formatting, button

Is there a way to add a rounded border/background on only one word in a paragraph in indesign ?

Or a way to have a dynamic object that can be put in a paragraph and edited by double clicking to get something like this easy to update ?

[image: tags in indesign]

Thx a lot :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Styling characters into a pragraph](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/137257/styling-characters-into-a-pragraph)

Comment: Something I noticed that's unrelated to your question, but just in case the image is part of your project, the word "photographies" is not used in English. Photography is an uncountable noun, and the plural of photograph is photographs.

Comment: A background is doable (see Lucian’s answer), but if you’re looking for the full effect shown in the image, that’s far too complex to be doable inline. You’d have to use anchored objects with an object style applied (and I’m not even sure it’s fully possible with just an object style).

Answer (score 2):

There are limitations, but something like this can be achieved with a custom underline character style. With this, you can just select any words in a paragraph, hit the character style, and it gets applied automatically with no changes to the text flow.

[image]

[image]